# What is an effective way to test if a descriptor has already been unwrapped or not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, descriptor, python-descriptors

Suppose we have the following class:

```
class K:
    # classmethod creates a descriptor
    @classmethod 
    def cm(cls, a, b, c):
        pass
```

Now, we obtain the `cm` attribute in the following way:

```
import random
getters = [
    lambda attr_name: object.__getattribute__(K, '__dict__')[attr_name]
    lambda attr_name: getattr(cm, attr_name)
]
geht = random.choice(getters)
cm = geht('cm')
```

**What is an effective way to test which `cm` we just got?**
(we don't have direct access to class K, only the `cm` returned by `geht`)

The `random.choice` is highly contrived, but there are instances where we have a container of pseudo-attributes, and we want to verify that they've either all not been unwrapped yet, or verify that they have been unwrapped.

*One Failed Approach*

One might be tempted to think that the descriptor has a `__get__()` method and that the object returned by `__get__()` does not.

However, the `__get__` method of a function decorated with `@classmethod` returns an object which also has a `__get__` method.

*Properties of wrapped and unwrapped class method*

```
# still wrapped cm 
type                <class 'classmethod'>
hasattr  __get__    True
hasattr  __call__   False

# unwrapped cm
type                <class 'method'>
hasattr  __get__    True
hasattr  __call__   True
```

I am tempted to think that we can test the pseudo-attribute to see if it has a `__call__` method or not. However, I would like the solution to work for descriptors in general, not just `classmethod`s. For any attribute, `d` of a class having a `__get__` method, it would be nice to determine whether some reference `ref` is a reference to `d` or the value returned by `d.__get__()` (assuming that `d.__get__()` does not return `d`)

Answer (score 0):

There is no general solution. Any possible descriptor is also a possible `__get__` return value. You would need more information than just the object to determine this.